# cakephp 3 check duplicate email and send message the email already exit

Tags: cakephp

When user get Registration using registration form this time 
if email already email exist in data base this show a message "the email Already exist" others user can complete registration.
but can't show message what am i wrong?

My Controller

```
public function emailCheck()
{
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->viewBuilder()->layout('false');
    if ($this->request->is(['post'])) {
         $search =$this->request->data('email');                                                  
         $query = $this->Users->find('list', [
                              'conditions' => ['Users.email LIKE '=>'%' .$search. '%'],
                              'limit' => 1
                              ])->all();
         foreach ($query as $key) {
             if($key!=null){
                echo "This email has been taken!!";
             }else
             echo "Email avilable.";
         }
    } 
}
```

My Ajax

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('input[name="email"]').change(function(){
        var email = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
                  method:'POST',
                  url:'<?php echo Router::url(['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'emailCheck']); ?>',
                  data:{search:email},
                  success: function(data)
                  {
                    alert(data);
                  }
        });
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly:
You state `find('list')` but end your query with `all()` which returns an array of objects (even if you limit it to 1). So your `$key` will never be just `null`.
You can however just try to find the first record using the given email:

```
$query = $this->Users->find('list', [
           'conditions' => ['Users.email LIKE'=> $search],
          ])->first();

 if (is_null($query)) {
     // the email is still available
 } else {
     // the email is already in use
 }
```

**Note:**
I also removed the `%` wildcards from your query: leaving them there would result in false positives, eg: `123johndoe@gmail.com` would get the message his email is already in use when someone would have subscribed with `johndoe@gmail.com`

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the solution.the solution are 
My Controller

```
    public function emailCheck()
{
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->viewBuilder()->layout('false');
    if ($this->request->is(['post'])) {
        $email =$this->request->data('email');                                                 
        $query = $this->Users->find()
            ->where(['Users.email '=>$email])->count();
        if($query) {
             echo 1;
        }
    }
}
```

My Ajax

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#email').keyup(function(){
        var email = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
                  method:'POST',
                  url:'<?php echo Router::url(['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'emailCheck']); ?>',
                  dataType: "text",
                  data:{email:email},
                  success: function(data)
                  {
                      if(data){
                          $( ".result" ).html('<span style="color:red">Someone already has that username. Try another?</span>');
                      }else{
                         $( ".result" ).html('<span style="color:green">The email is still available!!</span>');
                      }

                  }
        });
    })
```

})

those script completely work to check duplicate email.testing by me